# What's the difference between local device memory and dedicated memory?

Tags: vulkan

In the specification, I saw several extensions for work with a so-called *dedicated memory*. My understanding is that this is the on-chip memory. But how then it differs from *local device memory*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the documentation of the `VK_KHR_dedicated_allocation` extension we can read:

> This extension enables resources to be bound to a dedicated allocation, rather than suballocated. For any particular resource, applications can query whether a dedicated allocation is recommended, in which case using a dedicated allocation may improve the performance of access to that resource.

So I think the difference is not between *dedicated* memory and *device-local* memory but between *dedicated* allocation and *normal/general* suballocation. But where is this memory object allocated from that's another story. And extension allows to check if dedicated allocation is suggested or if given resource can use part of (can suballocate from) a larger memory.

Comment: Right, dedicated means that there is a 1:1 relationship between the resource and the memory object. It's required for some external memory handle types, but other than that is never required. Some implementations (well, only one that I know of) have some relatively small efficiency benefits with dedicated allocations in some cases, and will indicate these with `prefersDedicatedAllocation`.